# Spatial interpolation of discrete points onto x/y coordinate mesh grid in Python

Tags: python, interpolation, cartopy, contourf, discrete

I'm still very new to programming and trying to create a contour plot of alkalinity across Hawaii using Cartopy. I will need to interpolate the point values called MODIFIED_TA against an x-y mesh grid but have not been able to figure out how to do this. The code I'm using is:

```
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.mpl.ticker as cticker
import statistics
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import numpy as np
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # ignoring the warning prompts.

%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=-170))

landgreen = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '110m', 
                                        edgecolor='face', facecolor='green')


oceanaqua = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', '110m', 
                                       edgecolor='face', facecolor='aqua')


ax.set_extent([-151.5, -162, 18, 24], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_title('TOTAL ALKALINITY')
ax.add_feature(landgreen)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN, color = 'k')
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)


lon_formatter = cticker.LongitudeFormatter()
lat_formatter = cticker.LatitudeFormatter()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
ax.grid(linewidth=2, color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')


lons = all_data.LONGITUDE[:]
lats = all_data.LATITUDE[:]
alk = all_data.MODIFIED_TA[:]
x1,y1 = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
z1,z2 = np.meshgrid(all_data.MODIFIED_TA,all_data.MODIFIED_TA)


plt.tricontourf(lons,lats,alk, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap=cm.gist_rainbow)
plt.colorbar(shrink=0.5)
plt.title('$A_{T}$ VALUES', color = 'k', fontname='Times New Roman',size = 23)

plt.plot()
```

The result is nothing like what I was hoping for and again, I'm not sure how to interpolate this value so that it comes out as a smooth gradient across the x/y coordinate grid. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[See output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhzkE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure without being able to see your data. I tried to create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and it worked. I would start by seeing if this works.

```
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.mpl.ticker as cticker
import numpy as np
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=-170))

ax.set_extent([-151.5, -162, 18, 24], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)


lon_formatter = cticker.LongitudeFormatter()
lat_formatter = cticker.LatitudeFormatter()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
ax.grid(linewidth=2, color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')

lons = np.random.random(80) * 7 - 160
lats = np.random.random(80) * 4 + 19
alk = np.cos(lons * 10 * np.pi / 180) * np.sin(lats * 20 / 180)

plt.plot(lons, lats, 'k.', transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.tricontourf(lons,lats,alk, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), alpha = 0.5)
plt.colorbar(shrink=0.5)
plt.title('$A_{T}$ VALUES', color = 'k', fontname='Times New Roman',size = 23)
```

[image: map]

If it does work, then what I'd look at would include:

- What are the dimensions of `all_data.LONGITUDE`, `all_data.LATITUDE`, `all_data.MOTIFIED_TA`?
- Are there duplicate values?
- Does it work when you plot it outside of a projection?

If my example does not work, then it suggests there is something about your install, in which case update it if you can. If the problem still persists, perhaps there is a bug `cartopy` that needs reporting or a conflict with other packages.

Sorry, I cannot help further.

Comment: Thank you!! I was able to get it to work. In the meantime, I ended up getting some help setting up a data interpolation loop and was able to regrid the data set in the process and essentially map the interpolated results over the Cartopy grid. Also, I was able to get the example that you sent to run without any issues and will definitely be referring to it for future reference. I really appreciate your help!